# How to calculate month from number of days in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, clock

So basically I have done a calculation that increments a clock time:

```
function Clock(year,month,day,hours,minutes,seconds){

  if(seconds !== null){
  this.seconds = seconds;
  }

  if(minutes !== null){
  this.minutes = minutes;
  }

  if(hours !== null){
  this.hours = hours;
  }

   if(day !== null){
  this.day = day;
  }

  if(month !== null){
  this.month = month;
  }

  if(year !== null){
  this.year = year;
  }

}


function incrementClock(){

clock.seconds++;
  if (clock.seconds >=60) {
    clock.seconds = 0;
    clock.minutes++;
    if (clock.minutes >=60) {
      clock.minutes = 0;
      clock.hours++;
      if (clock.hours >=24) {
        clock.hours = 0;
        clock.days++;
      }       
    }
  }    
}



function showClock(){

//prints clock in format yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss

}
```

This would increment the seconds, minutes, hours and days accordingly...

So if I call print the clock each second it would look like this:

```
var c = new Clock(2014,04,01,12,13,01);

showClock();
```

> 2014/4/1 12:13:1

I get stuck on the month part...

**My question is how would I go about checking if a month has passed as there are different amount of days each month?**

**EDIT**

I am creating my own minified Date function... so please don't recommend using `Date` objects as I am trying to implement my own

Comment: (Psst -- you should be checking either against `undefined` instead of `null`.  If there a parameter value not passed it, it will be `undefined.`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
function incrementClock(){
  clock.seconds++;
  if (clock.seconds >=60) {
    clock.seconds = 0;
    clock.minutes++;
    if (clock.minutes >=60) {
      clock.minutes = 0;
      clock.hours++;
      if (clock.hours >=24) {
        clock.hours = 0;
        clock.days++;
        var months = [31,((clock.year%4==0)&&((clock.year%100!=0)||(clock.year%400==0)))?29:28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];
        if (clock.days>months[clock.month-1]){
          clock.days = 0;
          clock.months++;
        }
      }       
    }
  }    
}
```

This line:

```
var months = [31,((clock.year%4==0)&&((clock.year%100!=0)||(clock.year%400==0)))?29:28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];
```

creates an array of the months and the days in each month. Thus it is easy to determine the amount of days per month like so:

```
days_in_jan = months[0]
days_in_feb = months[1]
...
days_in_dec = months[11]
```

Comment: What does the `if (clock.days>months[clock.month-1]){` do exactly? in particular the `month-1` part

Comment: it determines of the current day is exceeding the amount of days in the current month. The amount of days in the current month is this: "months[clock.month-1]". Assuming January is month 1. If it is 0 then use "months[clock.month]" instead.

Comment: Yes but I still don't understand what the `-1` is for?

Comment: It depends on how you store clock.month. If 1 is considered january then the 0th memory slot in months corresponds with january, so you subtract one. However, if you are considering 0 january, then you can remove the -1.

Comment: Awesome! Does that answer your question completely now?

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  You don't increment anything actually.  If you want your own clock, that's fine, but you still need to access the current time using a `Date` object, so when you want to know how much time has elapsed, get a new `Date` object and figure it out:

pseudo structure:

```
Class Clock
    - start date

    - function timeElapsed
        - elapsed = now - start date
```

In that function, compare the month, day, etc.

And honestly, if you don't like that answer you're on your own, as the answer to "how do I do this random thing as purely a thought exercise" is exactly that -- a thought exercise.  There's no real point to it, so it shouldn't be asked *or* answered on SO.

Comment: I am free to ask any question I want... There is a point in this. I am learning how to code in JavaScript and I find these kind of tasks interesting. Oh and it's not 'how do I do this random thing as purely a thought exercise', I have a problem and that is what Stackoverflow is for...

Comment: Although I generally agree with you, I feel like you're discounting "real" solutions in favor of doing it in your own specific, wrong way.  That's fine for thought exercises, and I encourage it in general, especially to learn a language.  But that type of question is completely useless to anyone else, so I feel like it should be kept off of SO.  It's like if I went to a construction forum and asked "How would I build a house with only paperclips?"  It might be an interesting challenge, but it's really only interesting to the person asking it and serves no real purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As others have done, I would suggest using the Date object, or a date library like MomentJS, but it seems like you want to do the implementation yourself as an exercise.  In that case, your code will need to know how many days are in each month if it is going to do the calculation correctly.  Consider including in your code an array of the months' lengths:

```
var monthLengths = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
```

You'll also need a function to determine whether or not it's a leap year:

```
function isLeapYear(year) {
  return (year % 4 == 0) && ((year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0));
}
```

Armed with those, you should be able to tell if a date has exceeded its month by checking the array to know how many days are in that month, and (if it's February) using the leap year function to determine if you should count 29 days for February.